# Patterning COUT by inches/feet of pallets (C++ help)

Tags: c++

doin a little project to try and better my C++ knowledge, I might be doing it wrong and any guidance in the right direction would be more than appreciated. Just a heads up I am an amateur when it comes to C++..

What im trying to do: 
Make a program that calculates pallets in a commercial truck, our standard truck dimensions are 96 inches (or 8 ft) in width and 636 inches (or 53 ft) in length.

Pallet sizes can vary, and I need two dims from them (length/width).

When it comes to standard pallets (40 inches by 48 inches) you can fit 30 pallets total: 15 of them side by side.

If one pallet is 53x50 and one is 47x51, these two wouldn't fit together because it exceeds the limit of 96 OR less inches.

I need this program to make it so it adds all different types of sizes and shows it in a rectangle "cout" format by placing pallets together to fit in the way that saves the most space.

I assume this would require if, then statements when outputting dims into the "trailer"

Example:

If I had 7 pallets total with the following dims (in inches):

101x57, 45x31, 101x43, 107x43, 124x61, 96x18, 56x49

Out put in the box "trailer" would be:

EDIT: edited output of the trailer example

```
--------------------
| 101x57     45x31 |
|                  |
|           107x43 |
|                  |
| 101x43           |
|            96x18 |
|                 
| 124x61     56x49 |   
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
--------------------
```

This is the most efficient way to pattern them with saving the most space.

// CODE BELOW: I know its not much, but I just started and I'm already stuck :/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double p1d1, p1d2, p2d1, p2d2, p3d1, p3d2, p4d1, p4d2, p5d1, p5d2, p6d1, p6d2, p7d1, p7d2, p8d1, p8d2;
double palletSize2;

const double pRSize = 96.001;

int main()
{

    cout << "Partial Counter 1.0" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter pallet sizes one at a time " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Pallet #1 dims" << endl;
    cout << "Dims: ";
    cin >> p1d1 >> p1d2;
    cout << "Dim 2: ";
    cin >> p1d2;
    cout << "Pallet #1 Dims = " << p1d1 << "x" << p1d2 << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Pallet #2 dims" << endl;
    cout << "Dim 1: ";
    cin >> p2d1;
    cout << "Dim 2: ";
    cin >> p2d2;
    cout << "Pallet #2 Dims = " << p1d1 << "x" << p1d2 << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Pallet #3 dims" << endl;
    cout << "Dim 1: ";
    cin >> p3d1;
    cout << "Dim 2: ";
    cin >> p3d2;
    cout << "Pallet #3 Dims = " << p1d1 << "x" << p1d2 << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Pallet #4 dims" << endl;
    cout << "Dim 1: ";
    cin >> p4d1;
    cout << "Dim 2: ";
    cin >> p4d2;
    cout << "Pallet #4 Dims = " << p1d1 << "x" << p1d2 << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Pallet #5 dims" << endl;
    cout << "Dim 1: ";
    cin >> p5d1;
    cout << "Dim 2: ";
    cin >> p5d2;
    cout << "Pallet #5 Dims = " << p1d1 << "x" << p1d2 << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Pallet #6 dims" << endl;
    cout << "Dim 1: ";
    cin >> p6d1;
    cout << "Dim 2: ";
    cin >> p6d2;
    cout << "Pallet #6 Dims = " << p1d1 << "x" << p1d2 << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Pallet #7 dims" << endl;
    cout << "Dim 1: ";
    cin >> p7d1;
    cout << "Dim 2: ";
    cin >> p7d2;
    cout << "Pallet #7 Dims = " << p1d1 << "x" << p1d2 << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Pallet #8 dims" << endl;
    cout << "Dim 1: ";
    cin >> p8d1;
    cout << "Dim 2: ";
    cin >> p8d2;
    cout << "Pallet #8 Dims = " << p1d1 << "x" << p1d2 << endl;


    cout << " ------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << "|                              |" << endl;
    cout << " -----------------------------" << endl;



}
```

Comment: Seems like this is an algorithm question.  The model for S.O. is for you to submit a small code snippet that is giving you trouble and to ask for help on that section of the code.  Algorithms are covered at https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: To be honest, this sounds like an **extremely** difficult problem for a self-confessed amateur. I think most professionals would regard this as challenging. Finding an algorithm that 'saves the most space' is the challenging part.

Comment: That is enough to be considered helpful, thank you! I will work to learn about algorithms and when I come up with some code that gets me close to my desired program I will ask in that forum for more help.